# Google Apps Script access to scripts has stopped working for other users which are spreadsheet editors

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

Thanks in advance for reading my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I have implemented over the years many GAS scripts across many of my company's spreadsheets (bound scripts) to the point that the company has become completely reliant on these scripts in order to issue invoices, communicate with clients and many other tasks.

For some reason I cannot fathom, since more or less last week, I am the only user that can access these scripts, even though all other users have editing rights to all the relevant spreadsheets.

*Let me stress the point that these scripts have worked fine for years.*

As an example, many of these scripts leverage the inbuilt onOpen() trigger to create a custom menu which gives access to many functions. Well, now it seems that the only user which gets the custom menu is me.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('DX')
    .addItem('Nueva Reserva', 'newBookingForm')
    .addItem('Editar Reserva', 'preEditCheck')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Activar Reserva', 'pre_activate')
    .addItem('Cancelar Reserva', 'pre_cancel')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Generar contrato', 'preContract')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Mandar email', 'email2ClientInit')
    .addToUi();
}
```

I happen to be the owner of all of the spreadsheets in my company so I guess that's why at least I can still use the scripts.

In case it is relevant, most of these scripts also rely on a couple of libraries that I have created, and which are also shared with the relevant company members with editing rights, and all of the spreadsheets live in Shared Drives of which all of the relevant members are Managers.

Moreover, when trying to open the script tab as a user that is not the owner by clicking the menu "Extensions" and choosing "Apps Script", I get an error message saying "script.google.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

This page then resolves into a page showing "Bad Request ERR 400".

Needless to say that clearing the cookies and signing back in doesn't solve the issue.

This problem, obviosly, has huge implications for my company since these spreadsheets permeate virtually everything we do and all relevant users need to be able to access the bound scripts.

Let me share three screenshots, one for the Sharing popup window to show the Editing permissions, one for the first error message mentioned and another for the Bad Request page.

[Permissions window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQjhA.png)

[image]

Redirection error

[Bad Request resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUmYK.png)

[image]

Comment: A menu of function is not going to be sufficient to assist you.  We require [mcve].  We cannot fix things that we can't create.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper for looking into this. I have read the documentation you provided and I thought I met all the points listed therein, but obviously not if you could not work with what I wrote. 
I have since found a way around the problem, which I will post as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have zoned in on the problem.

For some reason, I have had to update the permissions to the files to something different than what was before.

It seems it wasn't enough that all people listed in the "People with access" area of the Sharing menu had editing rights to the file. After changing the General Access from the same Sharing menu to a *group* and giving the group editing rights so that it shows "Anyone in this group can link and edit" is what has solved the problem for us.

I hope anyone else who finds him/herself in this same situation finds this question useful, and thanks to all who have looked into it.